# Change the color inside the plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

In this plot

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(year = c(2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018), 
                 value = c(337,423,551,661,846,1387,2222,3580))

ggplot(df, aes(year, value)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  geom_text(aes(label = value, y = (value - 50)*0.9))
```

How is it possible to make the color of numbers of value red?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(year = c(2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018), 
                 value = c(337,423,551,661,846,1387,2222,3580))

ggplot(df, aes(year, value)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  geom_text(aes(label = value, y = (value - 50)*0.9), color = "red")
```

[image: example.png]

Or like this?

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(year = c(2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018), 
                 value = c(337,423,551,661,846,1387,2222,3580))

ggplot(df, aes(year, value)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  geom_text(aes(label = value, y = (value - 50)*0.9), color = "red") +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(colour = "red"))
```

[image: example_2.png]